# Python list not callable using proxies

Tags: python, list, proxies

Im creating a script that NEEDS to connect to a proxy. However while connecting, I'm making it use a list so its easily adaptable and i don't need to keep updating the proxies, just upload a new file...
I get this error when i run it..
    `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

```
import urllib2
from random import choice

lines = []

for line in open('proxies.txt', 'r'):
    lines.append(line.strip())


proxynew = lines(1)
proxy  = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': proxynew})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
your_ip = opener.open('http://ip.42.pl/i').read()
print 'IP: ' + your_ip
```

Comment: Sorry guys, TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 4):

The immediate problem is with this line:

```
proxynew = lines(1)
```

To access elements of a list use brackets:

```
proxynew = lines[1]
```

---

If you want the first element of the list, please note that Python uses a zero-based index.
Therefore the first element is accessed like this:

```
proxynew = lines[0]
```

Comment: It seems when i use that i get this now...

urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>

Comment: This should probably be a different question as it is now unrelated to the first error, but try adding a `print` statement to see if the value of `proxynew` is what you expect.